# Multiple regression with lagged time series using libsvm

Tags: regression, svm, libsvm

I'm trying to develop a forecaster for electric consumption. So I want to perform a regression using daily data for an entire year. My dataset has several features. Googling I've found that my problem is a [Multiple regression](https://www.google.com/search?q=multiple%20regression) problem (Correct me please if I am mistaken).

What I want to do is train a `svm` for regression with several independent variables and one dependent variable with n lagged days. Here's a sample of my independent variables, I actually have around 10. (We used `PCA` to determine which variables had some correlation to our problem)

```
Day     Indep1    Indep2    Indep3
1       1.53      2.33      3.81
2       1.71      2.36      3.76
3       1.83      2.81      3.64
...     ...       ...       ...
363     1.5       2.65      3.25
364     1.46      2.46      3.27
365     1.61      2.72      3.13
```

And the independendant variable 1 is actually my dependant variable in the future. So for example, with a p=2 (lagged days) I would expect my `svm` to train with the first 2 time series of all three independant variables.

```
Indep1   Indep2    Indep3
1.53     2.33      3.81
1.71     2.36      3.76
```

And the output value of the dependent variable would be "1.83" (Indep variable 1 on time 3).

My main problem is that I don't know how to train properly. What I was doing is just putting all features-p in an array for my "x" variables and for my "y" variables I'm just putting my independent variable on p+1 in case I want to predict next day's power consumption.

Example of training.

```
x with p = 2 and 3 independent variables            y for next day
[1.53, 2.33, 3.81, 1.71, 2.36, 3.76]                [1.83]
```

I tried with x being a two dimensional array but when you combine it for several days it becomes a 3d array and `libsvm` says it can't be.

Perhaps I should change from `libsvm` to another tool or maybe it's just that I'm training incorrectly.

Thanks for your help,
Aldo.

Answer (score 1):

Let me answer with the python / numpy notation.

Assume the original time series data matrix with columns (Indep1, Indep2, Indep3, ...) is a numpy array `data` with shape `(n_samples, n_variables)`. Let's generate it randomly for this example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> n_samples = 100, n_variables = 5
>>> data = np.random.randn(n_samples, n_variables)
>>> data.shape
(100, 5)
```

If you want to use a window size of 2 time-steps, then the training set can be built as follows:

```
>>> targets = data[2:, 0]  # shape is (n_samples - 2,)
>>> targets.shape
(98,)
>>> features = np.hstack([data[0:-2, :], data[1:-1, :]])  # shape is (n_samples - 2, n_variables * 2)
>>> features.shape
(98, 10)
```

Now you have your 2D input array + 1D targes that you can feed to libsvm or [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org).

**Edit**: it might very well be the case that extracting more time-series oriented features such as moving average, moving min, moving max, moving differences (time based derivatives of the signal) or [STFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-time_Fourier_transform) might help your SVM mode make better predictions.

Comment: With 2 time-steps you are saying that training will occur with the target in time +2? How about using lagged days? (making the training/prediction of a certain day to be calculated with p days * n_features ).

Comment: Nevermind, I finished understanding/testing your suggestion. I had my data pretty much like that but something weird is happening in the training. When doing validation it always give me the same output and I'm changing my targets.

Comment: You need to do a grid search for the optimal values of the parameters (e.g. C and gamma for a SVR model with a gaussian kernel). Please see the documentation of libsvm or scikit-learn for more details.